# Get image path, width and height and put them into input fields by uploading an image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a form with several text inputs and one file input.

```
<table>

<tr>
<td>PlanID *</td>
<td><input type="file" name="file" id="file" placeholder="file" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>URL *</td>
<td><input type="text" name="url" id="url" placeholder="Image URL" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Height *</td>
<td><input type="number" name="height" id="height" placeholder="Height" />     
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>width *</td>
<td><input type="number" name="width" id="width" placeholder="Width" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="submit" name="sub" id="sub" value="Upload"       
class="buttons"/></td>
<td><input type="reset" name="res" id="res" value="Cancel" class="buttons"/>   
</td>
</tr>


</table>
```

I need to fill these URL, width and height fields in particular details by uploading an image. How could I do this??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My proposal is:

- add after input type file `<img id="imgTogetWidthAndHeight" src="" style="display: none;"/>`
- on file change: get the url and load image into the hidden img tag
- on image load: get width and heigth

In order to upload these data you need to wrap your table in a form or use and ajax call or plugin.

```js
$(function () {
  
  $('#file').on('change', function(e) {
    var tmppath = URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0]);
    $("#imgTogetWidthAndHeight").attr('src',tmppath);
    var url = $(this).val();
    $('#url').val(url);
  });
  
  $("#imgTogetWidthAndHeight").on('load', function(e) {
    var width = parseInt($("#imgTogetWidthAndHeight").css('width'));
    var height = parseInt($("#imgTogetWidthAndHeight").css('height'));
    $('#width').val(width);
    $('#height').val(height);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td>PlanID *</td>
        <td><input type="file" name="file" id="file" placeholder="file"/><img id="imgTogetWidthAndHeight" src="" style="display: none;"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>URL *</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="url" id="url" placeholder="Image URL"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Height *</td>
        <td><input type="number" name="height" id="height" placeholder="Height"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>width *</td>
        <td><input type="number" name="width" id="width" placeholder="Width"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="submit" name="sub" id="sub" value="Upload"
                   class="buttons"/></td>
        <td><input type="reset" name="res" id="res" value="Cancel" class="buttons"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```